# How to remove an event listener with different event parameter?

Tags: javascript, events, actionscript, listener

I've got an event listener that happened with "mousemove" Parameter:

```js
currentCardEl.addEventListener("mousemove", updateCard);
```

can I use removeEventListener with another Parameter to remove this function?

```js
currentCardEl.removeEventListener("mouseleave", updateCard, true);
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? why `removeEventListener` when you never added a listener for `mouseleave`?

Comment: thank you! I've resolve the problem )

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so, that a sertian condition is met when you dont want to make the event. Not sure otherwise

```
temp.addEventListner(MouseEvent.CLICK, thisIsTheFunction);

function thisIsTheFunction(evt:MouseEvent){
   if(){ //Here you have the condition

   }
}
```